# Can't Write Streamed Data To SD Card Of My Galaxy S2 Using MonoDroid via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-sdcard

I am having a lot of trouble in working with streams using monodroid. What I am trying to do is simply download a file using a URL and saving it to my phone's /sdcard location but am having problems. I am getting **Access to the path '/mnt/sdcard' is denied.**

Code :-

```
Filestream strlocal;
var fileName = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
string path = Convert.ToString(fileName);
strLocal = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
```

- When I debug the app and try to run it on my device, the debugging error points at this line of code.

In Visual Studio, I have made the manifest file using the dialog in properties in which I have given permission to write, i.e :-

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Also , i Tried another approach to write this permission in the main activity page, i.e :-

```
[Activity(Label = "MonoAndroidApplication2", MainLauncher = true, 
Permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
```

But still getting the same error of denial. Also when I make the manifest file in visual studio, I get strange messages like:-

```
Message 5   Could not find schema information for the element 'uses-permission'.    

Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element 'manifest'.

Message 2   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'package'.
```

What do these messages mean?. Please help me in this problem.

**I am using the latest version of Monodroid (Bought it a week ago)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to open the FileStream using the folder's path, rather than specifying a file name within that folder. For example:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "MyFile.txt");

using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    // write stuff
}
```

This will create a file named MyFile.txt in the external storage folder.

Comment: oh, I see.. so the Message :  Could not find schema information for the element 'uses-permission'.. Is that any problem ??.. Thanks for the response :).

Comment: I think you're just referring to a warning shown in Visual Studio, right? If so it just means that VS doesn't know what the schema is for that file so it doesn't know about the element, so you can ignore it.

Comment: yes the message was shown in visual studio. Thanks for the support ! :)